# Find window by partial name search in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Is there a way to use `FindWindowByWindowName()` with partial matches (or wildcards)?

I have a file name in the window name so it can vary based on the name of the file that is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more specific answer based on the other answer by Martin Prikryl is:

```
[Code]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------}

type
    EnumWindowsParam=record
      hWnd : HWND;
      Name : String;
    end;  

function EnumWindows(lpEnumFunc: LongWord; var lParam: EnumWindowsParam): Boolean;
  external 'EnumWindows@user32.dll stdcall';

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------}

function GetWindowText(hWnd: HWND; lpString: string; nMaxCount: Integer): Integer;
  external 'GetWindowTextW@user32.dll stdcall';

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------}
function IsWindowVisible(hWnd: HWND): Boolean;
  external 'IsWindowVisible@user32.dll stdcall';

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------}
{ parameter must use lower case name for matching }
function EnumWindowsProc(hwnd: HWND; var lparam: EnumWindowsParam): Boolean;
var
  windowname: string;
  windownamelen: Integer;
begin
  { continue search }
  Result := True;
  { ensure normal visible window }
  if IsWindowVisible(hWnd) then
  begin
    { setup buffer to get window name from - name truncated if too large for buffer  }
    SetLength(windowname, 256);
    windownamelen := GetWindowText(hwnd, windowname, 256);
    SetLength(windowname, windownamelen);
    if windowname <> '' then
    begin
      { work with lower case names for matching }
      windowname:=lowercase(windowname);
      if WildcardMatch(windowname, lparam.Name) then
      begin
        { found item }
        lparam.hWnd:=hwnd;
        { don't need to enumerate additional windows }
        Result := False;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------}

function FindWindowByWildcard(var windowname: string) : HWND;
var
  enumresults : ENumWindowsParam;
begin
  { setup parameter structure }
  enumresults.Name:=lowercase(windowname);
  enumresults.hWnd:=0;
  
  { make call }
  EnumWindows(CreateCallback(@EnumWindowsProc), enumresults);

  { provide result }
  Result:=enumresults.hWnd;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

This will log names of all windows.

```pascal
function EnumWindows(lpEnumFunc: LongWord; lParam: LongWord): Boolean;
  external 'EnumWindows@user32.dll stdcall';

function GetWindowText(hWnd: HWND; lpString: string; nMaxCount: Integer): Integer;
  external 'GetWindowTextW@user32.dll stdcall';

function EnumWindowsProc(hWnd: HWND; lParam: LongWord): Boolean;
var
  Buf: string;
  Len: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;
  SetLength(Buf, 256);
  Len := GetWindowText(hWnd, Buf, 256);
  SetLength(Buf, Len);
  if Buf <> '' then
  begin
    Log(Buf);
  end;
end;

procedure FindAllWindows;
begin
  EnumWindows(CreateCallback(@EnumWindowsProc), 0);
end;
```

Modify it to find only the names that match your criteria.

If needed/appropriate, you can use `IsWindowVisible` to filter to visible windows only.

*Based on:*
*https://github.com/KngStr/Inno-All-in-One-Setup/blob/master/Examples/CallbackCtrl/test2.iss*
*Only simplified with use of the new features of Inno Setup 6 (`CreateCallback` in particular)*